# MacOS: Modify secure boot T2 settings without Recovery Mode?

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I have a Macbook Pro with T2 security chip. I was making a recovery of a Time Machine backup, that somehow failed. Could not boot up after it. Somehow also the Recovery Mode partition is gone. Now I cannot boot from USB, make Internet Recovery, nor anything else. All ends up with "Security settings do not allow this Mac to use an external startup disk.".

Booting with "Option" key pressed, only shows the Catalina installation disk, but that fails with the above error.

And the Recovery Partition is gone, so I cannot Command+R into Recovery Mode and allow booting from external drive (as per this information: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330).

Is there any other path to set the T2 security settings? Meaning without Recovery Mode "Startup Security Utility".

Comment: Try booting in "augmented" (as in, CLI) Recovery Mode with the Command-R-S key combo. You'll be in Recovery Mode, but in Command Line instead of GUI. You'll have access to the regular repair tools there, such as "fsck". It'll do a more thorough job than your regular Safe Mode boot, which does a perfunctory "fsck" on startup and corrects minor errors in directory issues, without going too deep. It still must be possible to run AppleJack (https://sourceforge.net/projects/applejack/files/AppleJack/AppleJack-1.6/) from USB, provided you can boot on it, or install it in Safe Mode and run from there

Comment: @Didier it's worth noting that you cannot fsck (or mount) an APFS volume from CLI Recovery Mode. APFS is also now the default. There are still some limited uses for this mode (such as modifying nvram or using csrutil), Just wanted to point out that fsck is a bad example these days. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380691/fsck-apfs-not-working-from-terminal-in-single-user-mode

Comment: Regardless, if you launch diskutil, it'll wrap the "fsck_apfs" set of commands anyway. Additionally, you can force an fsck on startup with the "sudo touch /forcefsck" command in Terminal.

Comment: Even internet installation did not work, same error. However, after resetting NVRAM (https://support.apple.com/HT204063) I was able to make internet installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you need to erase and reinstall your MacBook. Have important data on your Mac? Unfortunately, every Mac with a T2 chip has a unique ID for encryption. So it's impossible to transfer data via Target Disk Mode. The only way is to download and install a T2 chip data recovery software like iBoysoft Data Recovery for Mac. Look at the post: https://iboysoft.com/mac-data-recovery/apple-t2-chip-data-recovery.html.

But data recovery is never guaranteed, especially when it's on the OS disk. If the lost data is overwritten, there is no way to get it back.

After data restore, the next step is to reinstall macOS. Shut down your Mac and restart it by pressing <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (not <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). This will lead you to erase the startup disk and reinstall macOS.

I hope it works. Good luck!